# How to set the qt gui sink display order in gnuradio?

Tags: qt, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I create simple `grc` flow in gnuradio as below:

[image]

The expected output show be:

- 1.qt gui sink
- 2.frequency sink
- 3.time sink

But time sink appear first,then gui sink:

[image]

How to set the qt gui sink display order in gnuradio?

Comment: Note that we've remarked that your version of GNU Radio seems to be very old. The answer Ben gives is correct, but I can't tell from your picture whether your GNU Radio is new enough to support it. **Update your GNU Radio to 3.8 or 3.9**; GNU Radio 3.7 and 3.6 (which we can tell from your screenshot) is in "legacy support mode" only, and **should not be used for new projects**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of elements in the GUI is ordered by ROWS and COLUMNS. They can be set in the GUI corresponding properties named 'GUI Hint'.

Example and overview can be found in the wiki:

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/GUI_Hint